# how to use activate.createinstance on 2d string array in reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, createinstance

Hi good people of SO,

I am facing a little challenge here and I can't quite figure it out. So I have a 2d array that I've created using the following :

```
var portTypes = assembly.GetExportedTypes();
string[,] commonIPPort= new string [2,2];
foreach (var v in portTypes )
        {
            if (v.FullName == "iControl.CommonIPPortDefinition")
            {
                commonIPPort= new string[,] { { v.Name, v.FullName }};
            }
        }
dynamic ports= Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object),commonIPPort.Length);
```

This is where I get the null error:
object item;

```
for (int i = 0; i < commonIPPort.Length; i++)
        {
            item = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(commonIPPort[i,i+1]));

        }
```

so my question is how do you use createinstance on a 2d string?

thank you in advance.

Comment: because I started with 0 index and it won't let it since it's null I figured that index started at 1

Comment: Notice what you did inside `if`. Are you creating instance when `if` condition was `true` or not? (can be checked with breakpoint). If not - then you have `[2,2]` array filled with `null` (the error you have), if yes - you will end up with `IndexOutOfRangeException` (because of `i + 1`).

Comment: I am basically creating instance if it finds 'iControl.CommonIPPortDefinition' coz there are 1300 objects there. and I'm trying to create that instance for  'ports' (ports= Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object),commonIPPort.Length);) coz the next line is ports.address and ports.portnumber

Comment: Start with posting exact error message and stack trace. More likely you have `ArgumentNullException` in [`GetType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx), then just set a breakpoint on it and inspect `i` and `commonIPPort[i, i+1]` values. I bet you will find a `null` there instead of string. Why? I tried to explain earlier: `v.FullName` is never `iControl.whatever` and you have empty array filled with `null`'s. But even if `if` condition would be true you will still end up with `IndexOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: Yes you're right it is null value. I will have to redo it ! thanks @Sinatr